# How do I make a command that makes an activity graph discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make a command that makes a graph of activity. When I type !graph activity, I want it to show how many messages have been sent the past 7 days and so far today. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What code do you currently have and what issues are you having? If you don't have anything start at reading a guide on programming discord bots https://discordjs.guide/. You will also likely need some library for creating a graph and maybe a database so read up on those.

Comment: @Tim, I currently don't have any code, what I'm looking for is how to start this process. I have an idea of how to make the graph, but I'm not sure how to make the bot count messages sent. is there a specific API for that?

Comment: Have you tried working through the guide for discord.js I sent? That should go through all the basics of getting a bot setup which you will need for this. You should get fairly soon to where you can get a function which is called each time a message is sent and then use that.